# why Loadrunner Correlation is getting failed

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I want to correlate this 181-418-5889 in the following statement: regSend&transferNumber=181-418-5889".
I used the regular web_reg_save_param: But it failed... any suggestion?

Comment: Could you maybe add more details of what you did and what was the error. It is hard to tell you something from this generic description.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using the statement in the wrong location, such as using it just before the request is sent containing the correlated value versus just before the location where the response containing the value is sent to the client
2. You are not receiving the correct page response and as a result you may not be able to collect the value.  The page may be an HTTP 200 page but the content could be completely off.   Always check for an appropriate expected result
3. Your left boundary, right boundary and other parameters are incorrect to collect the value you need
4. You have not been through training and you are being forced by your management to learn this tool via trial and error

Comment: Thanks for your reply James even though you did not add anything to solve out the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

1- I am not using the statement in the wrong location since I did find the needed value I want to correlate via the Tree function and put it just before the statement that hold this value
2- The Page is not an HTTP 200 
3- The Left and right boundary are correct since I checked the text if it does exist twice in the response body. 
4- I know the tool (Loadrunner) but in fact, the application is developed under ZK platform and I am not sure if ZK and Loadrunner are compatible knowing that I did implement the dtid function in my script to have a static desktop id each time I replay the process.

Comment: "Page is not an HTTP 200"   This may be the root of your issue.  A 3xx class page is a redirect.  A 4xx or 5xx class page is an error.   So, if the HTTP status is not 2xx  for a valid page then you could be searching through a non resolvable reference.